# Calculate the process of each step - in SQL

Tags: sql

Which includes steps in the process and status of each step.
For processions completed the "Done" step is last and its duration is 0
A process that is without a "Done" stage-it still continues to run the query
I need a query to add another column in the table that calculates the minutes of each step in the process
I would appreciate your help
Which Syntax is effective
added a Syntax of table creation and data:

```
Create table T_Step (
    employee_ID INT
  , Process_ID  int
  , Step_ID     int
  , Start_Date  Datetime
  , Step_Status varchar(30)
);

Insert into T_Step values
    ('1','1','1','2018-01-01 8:00' ,'Pending')
  , ('1','1','2','2018-01-01 9:30' ,'InService')
  , ('1','1','3','2018-01-01 9:45' ,'Done')
  , ('2','2','1','2018-01-02 11:32','Pending')
  , ('2','2','2','2018-01-02 11:40','InService')
  , ('2','2','3','2018-01-02 12:20','Done')
;
```

Thanks

Comment: Please mentioned weather this is s sql-server/mySql etc... also add what try tried and expected output

Comment: You haven't shown own effort wrt your problem but simply replaced the sample  contents with sql statements to recreate them. At the very least please tell which sql dialect you are working with.

Comment: *minutes of each step in the process* can you give some eample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and then count time difference between two-step for the particular process.

*This query work in* **MYSQL**

```
select t1.employee_ID,t1.Process_ID,t1.Step_ID,t1.Start_Date,t1.Step_Status,
IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t1.Start_Date,t2.Start_Date),0) As TimeInMinute
from T_Step t1
LEFT JOIN T_Step t2
ON t1.Process_ID=t2.Process_ID AND t1.Step_ID!=t2.Step_ID AND (t2.Step_ID-t1.Step_ID)=1
ORDER BY t1.Process_ID,t1.Step_ID;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| employee_ID | Process_ID | Step_ID | Start_Date          | Step_Status | TimeInMinute |
| ----------- | ---------- | ------- | ------------------- | ----------- | ------------ |
| 1           | 1          | 1       | 2018-01-01 08:00:00 | Pending     | 90           |
| 1           | 1          | 2       | 2018-01-01 09:30:00 | InService   | 15           |
| 1           | 1          | 3       | 2018-01-01 09:45:00 | Done        | 0            |
| 2           | 2          | 1       | 2018-01-02 11:32:00 | Pending     | 8            |
| 2           | 2          | 2       | 2018-01-02 11:40:00 | InService   | 40           |
| 2           | 2          | 3       | 2018-01-02 12:20:00 | Done        | 0            |
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i3q7hSR77N3uUkAg1Tac4s/0)

Comment: Thank you for the answer
But that's the message I got :
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'TIMESTAMPDIFF' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: which sql you are using Mysql,Oracle,or else?

Comment: try to use `datediff` instead of `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

Comment: Excellent is the answer
Thank you very much :)

Comment: @syyt Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare   @T_Step table  (
    employee_ID INT
  , Process_ID  int
  , Step_ID     int
  , Start_Date  Datetime
  , Step_Status varchar(30)
);

Insert into @T_Step values
    ('1','1','1','2018-01-01 8:00' ,'Pending')
  , ('1','1','2','2018-01-01 9:30' ,'InService')
  , ('1','1','3','2018-01-01 9:45' ,'Done')
  , ('2','2','1','2018-01-02 11:32','Pending')
  , ('2','2','2','2018-01-02 11:40','InService')
  , ('2','2','3','2018-01-02 12:20','Done')
;

with cte as (Select *, R=ROW_NUMBER()
            over(partition by employee_ID order by employee_ID)
            from @T_Step)

Select T1.employee_ID,T1.Process_ID,T1.Step_Status,t1.Start_Date,t2.Start_Date, DATEDIFF(SECOND,t2.Start_Date,t1.Start_Date) TimeTaken
from cte T1
    left join cte T2 on T1.R = T2.R+1 and T1.employee_ID = T2.employee_ID
order by T1.employee_ID
```

Comment: Time calculation is not accurate
For example between the first stage and the second stage should be 90 minutes by employee_ID 1
Between the first step and the second step

Comment: @syyt : so changing `DATEDIFF(SECOND...` to `DATEDIFF(MINUTE..` will give you it in minutes?